# Foreign Key cascade path in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

> "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.AttendanceSheets_dbo.AdulLiteracyTeachers_ALTName' on table 'AttendanceSheets' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.\r\nCould not create constraint. See previous errors."}

```
public class AttendanceSheet
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        public int Attendanceid { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("District")]
        [ForeignKey("District")]
        public int DistID { get; set; }

        public virtual District District { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("District")]

        [ForeignKey("AdulLiteracyTeachers")]
        public int ALTName { get; set; }
        public virtual AdulLiteracyTeachers AdulLiteracyTeachers { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Month")]
        public int Month { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Number Of Days")]
        public int Attandence { get; set; }
    }
```

Getting the above error while I am adding the controller using entity framework. Purpose is I want to pouplate whole Teacher list for attandance. I am using the foriegn key for teachers name

Answer (score 0):

In your data context file add

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

}
```

below where you have your DbSets defined.

This happens when there are multiple paths to delete on entity from another through foreign keys.

For example

```
EntityA - EntityB - EntityC - EntityD
EntityA - EntityC - EntityD
EntityA - EntityD
```

There are multiple paths to delete the related EntityD, sql server doesn't allow this.